# Can I store data like an excel file on the Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

(I use this site for the first time. I don't know why my question is not clear. Please let me know if I have done something wrong. I will fix it immediately. I'm really sorry...)

I am a university student studying Ethereum in South Korea. It is not a regular course but a personal study due to interest!

I would like to make a conceptual diagram of 'Smart Factory' using private ethereum blockchain.

Smart Factory uses several sensors: thermometer, hygrometer, accelerometer and so on.

I am currently curious about three things.

Numerous values measured by a sensor, for example an accelerometer measure 100 data per second for 10 minutes

It is 60,000 data, and the data volume will be about 20mb (assumption).

1. Is it possible to store all of this data on all nodes of the ethereum blockchain at this time? 
   Or can I just read the sensor value and do a simple command (raise the temperature in indoor, stop the machine and so on)? 
   This is because the data is stored like an excel file, not as simple as the transaction data.
2. More simply, is it possible to store 'file data' in a block such as an excel file in an ethereum blockchain?
3. There is no need for 'ether trading' in the private ethereum blockchain that I envision. 
   'gas' prevents malicious users from falling into an infinite loop, but what does 'Ether' do in the case of me?

I am a complete starter. Ultimately, I'd like to  implement a smart factory using few sensors(it's for PPT presentations, not for real), but knowledge has too many limitations.

Thank you so much for your answer to my question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2EZr.png)

Comment: Look at Swarm. Ethereum is like a virtual machine that only has RAM. If you want a "hard drive", you need to use something like swarm.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to store all of this data on all nodes of the ethereum blockchain at this time? Or can I just read the sensor value and do a simple command (raise the temperature in indoor, stop the machine and so on)? This is because the data is stored like an excel file, not as simple as the transaction data.**

Storing a data in the blockchain is costly. You have too much data that would result hefty amount of Ethereum.

**More simply, is it possible to store 'file data' in a block such as an excel file in an ethereum blockchain?**

Blockchain stores the data with the help of Smart Contracts and excel file can not be stored in the blockchain.

**There is no need for 'ether trading' in the private ethereum blockchain that I envision. 'gas' prevents malicious users from falling into an infinite loop, but what does 'Ether' do in the case of me?**

Ether will be use to charge you for the storage you will use to store the data in the blockchain.

Comment: Your answer has been a great help to me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be stored on Ethereum, but every transaction has a cost associated with it. The cost of the transaction is directly correlated to the size of transactions.

Storing excel data is not recommended.
Blockchain is a ledger (transaction data).
If the purpose is to maintain the provenance of data, take the hash of excel and add the hash as the data of the transaction and store excel as data in the off-chain database.

Every data storage on the blockchain has a cost associated in terms of ether.

Ether serves two purposes on the main net, firstly incentivizing the miners to include your transaction in a block and secondly stopping people from spamming the network. You will still have to deal with ether.

Comment: thank you for your reply!

Does your answer mean that you store the address (converted to a hash function) that points to the location of the data, not the Excel data itself?

I'm sorry but, If what I understand is true, could I know the address of a web page with related resources or 'Google search terms'?